# Module parse failed error for css loader

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack

I am trying to load a css file in my component .js file but while doing so I get this error :

**ERROR in ./stories/styles.css
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.**

I have added following rule in my webpack.config.js file to take care of loaders but am still getting the error.

```
rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s?css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'raw-loader', 'sass-loader', 'css-loader'],
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, '../css/'),
        ],
      },
```

My styles.css file looks like this:

```
.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
}

.row.dark {
    background: #303030;
}

.col {
    width: calc(100% - 400px);
    padding: 15px;
}

.row > .col:first-child {
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    max-width: 400px;
}
```

Do I need to add any other loader ? 
I even tried using import instead of require to get the styles.css file but it made no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpack loaders get processed from right to left, you need to change the config to:

```
rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'raw-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, '../css/'),
        ],
      },
```

- I am also unsure what the use of the `raw-loader` is here since it is used to loads files as a string - you might not need it

Comment: I did try your suggested change but it didn't work. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: I would also change the test to `/\.scss$/`, you would need to rename your files to have the `.scss` extension but any css should be valid sass. Also have you tried removing `raw-loader`?

Comment: So the problem was in the path that I was giving for css files. So after re-arranging the loaders like you suggested and changing the path it worked. Thanks :)

Comment: Ok great, glad you got it sorted...;)